# How to filter values in data frame by grouped values in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
id    value
a1      0
a1      1
a1      2
a1      3
a2      0
a2      1
a3      0
a3      1
a3      2
a3      3
```

I want to filter id's and leave only those which have value higher than 3. So in this example id a2 must be removed since it only has values 0 and 1. So desired result is:

```
id    value
a1      0
a1      1
a1      2
a1      3
a3      0
a3      1
a3      2
a3      3
a3      4
a3      5
```

How to to that in pandas?

Comment: Do the values have to be in order? Can there be duplicates so that [0,2,1,1,3] within an 'id' would still be kept, because there is at least one of each of the 4 required numbers

Comment: The last two rows of the result are not in the original dataset. Is that a mistake?

Comment: I don't understand why you accepted the answer of @DYZ (sorry DYZ) because it's not the expected outcome? Else update you post with the correct data for other people which have a similar problem can understand.

Comment: @Corralien I agree, my answer was incorrect. Probably because the question is not perfectly clear. I updated my answer, and it is still formally wrong because 3 is not higher than 3. Feel free to downvote it, no offense.

Comment: @DYZ. You're right the question is not clear and the OP doesn't answer. FYI, I never downvote, I prefer to discuss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated.**

Group by IDs and find their max values. Find the IDs whose max value is at or above 3:

```
keep = df.groupby('id')['value'].max() >= 3
```

Select the rows with the IDs that match:

```
df[df['id'].isin(keep[keep].index)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean mask to keep rows that match condition then replace bad `id` (a2) by the next `id` (a3). Finally, group again by `id` an apply a cumulative sum.

```
mask = df.groupby('id')['value'] \
         .transform(lambda x: sorted(x.tolist()) == [0, 1, 2, 3])

df1 = df[mask].reindex(df.index).bfill()
df1['value'] = df1.groupby('id').agg('cumcount')
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   id  value
0  a1      0
1  a1      1
2  a1      2
3  a1      3
4  a3      0
5  a3      1
6  a3      2
7  a3      3
8  a3      4
9  a3      5
```